# JQuery - Persist JSON Change

Tags: jquery, json, database

I currently have two javascript files: one simply stores a single javascript variable which represents my JSON data and the other is actual JQuery code. For what it is worth, this is how my javascript file that contains the JSON looks like:

```
var data = '[{"id":[1],"email":["admin"],"password":["admin"],"question":[null],"answer":[null]}]';
```

And my javascript file that contains the JQuery looks like:

```
var email = $('#settings form input[type="email"]').val();
var password = $('#settings form input[type="password"]').val();
var question = $('#settings form select option:selected').text();
var answer = $('#settings form input[type="text"]').val();

if (email.trim() && password.trim() && question.trim() && answer.trim()) {
    jsonData[0].email[idIndex] = email;
    jsonData[0].password[idIndex] = password;
    jsonData[0].question[idIndex] = question;
    jsonData[0].answer[idIndex] = answer;

    $('#settings').modal('toggle');
} else {
    alert('None of the fields may be left blank.');
}
```

The JSON will be updated when the code runs, but once the page is refreshed none of the data persists.

My question is how can I get the JSON data to persist when the JQuery changes its value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you intend to do with the data long term. If you need to store it for a long time or work with more than one set of data at once, this means you're going to have to post your form to an application listening on the server. If you *only* have those two JavaScript files and are serving them directly from nginx or Apache or what have you, you're going to need to build a small server application since an out-of-the-box web server isn't going to know what to do with your data. Node.js is a solid choice for this especially if you want to stick with JavaScript.

Anyway, once you have something listening on the backend you can post the form through a submit button or `jQuery.ajax` (if you don't know which you should do, go for the former) and have the server store it in a database. From there, the world is your oyster: you can pull the data out, slice and dice it, ship it who knows where.

There are many different kinds of database. Most are specialized for one purpose or another; if you don't have a specific need in mind, the relational family (PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL) are the most versatile.

If you only want to persist it very briefly in a single session and don't care about any of that other stuff, you could use the browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). I suspect that's not what you want, but it does technically satisfy your question and it's much simpler.

Comment: Thank you, ultimately what I've done is utilize MySql combined with Node.JS.